# VBA issues when trying to run a SQL query between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, date, excel-2010

To give a brief summary of the objective of this macro, I am trying to get the sum of cash between certain dates based on a set of parameters. I keep getting an error in VBA when I try to run a SQL query with a date. I'm not sure what the issue is but I think it's related to how I have the date formatted. I have tried running it multiple ways but keep getting a syntax error, whether it be related to 'a', '#', or 'table'.

Here's the query I'm using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub GetCashBalance()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String

StartDate = InputBox("Enter Start Date in mm/dd/yy format.")
EndDate = InputBox("Enter End Date in mm/dd/yy format.")

SQL = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=SERVER\ODS"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open SQL
Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT SUM(a.CASH)" & _
            "FROM CUSTOMER_DATA.dbo.TRANSACTION_HISTORY a" & _
            "LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DATA.dbo.DAILY_TRANSACTION b" & _
            "ON a.T01_KEY = b.T01_KEY" & _
            "WHERE PROC_DATE BETWEEN #StartDate# AND #EndDate#" & _
            "AND a.CODE NOT IN ('22','23','M','2-L','36-R')" & _
            "AND isnull(a.DESCRIPTION, '') NOT IN ('01','02','03','0DO1','0NF2');")

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Sheets(7).Range("A40").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error", vbCritical
End If

cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT SUM(a.CASH)" & _
            "FROM CUSTOMER_DATA.dbo.TRANSACTION_HISTORY a" & _
            "LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DATA.dbo.DAILY_TRANSACTION b" & _
            "ON a.T01_KEY = b.T01_KEY" & _
            "WHERE PROC_DATE BETWEEN '" & StartDate & "' AND '" & EndDate & _
            "# AND a.CODE NOT IN ('22','23','M','2-L','36-R')" & _
            "AND isnull(a.DESCRIPTION, '') NOT IN ('01','02','03','0DO1','0NF2');")
```

Take a look at below piece, that should be changed

```
BETWEEN '" & StartDate & "' AND '" & EndDate & _            
"' AND ....
```

I think it is better to use `ADODB.Command` and `Parameters` instead of doing a concatenation in the sql query.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the response. I'm still getting an incorrect syntax error, but this time it's near 'a'. Is this because VBA doesn't like the 'a' and 'b' after the FROM clause in the SQL query?

Comment: I know why I got the incorrect syntax error around 'a'. When I deleted the end of line continuations (" & _") and had the query on one line in VBA, everything ran perfectly. With that said, is there a way I can use multiple lines because I have more code that can't fit onto one line? Is this what you meant by using ADODB.Command and Parameters instead of concatenation? Sorry to ask if you already answered that, but I'm pretty new to VBA.

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to put a space before the quotations. Thanks for your help.